# Is there a document formatter extension for Solidity files within visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

I am used to formatting my code by using the (Ctrl + Shift + i) keyboard shortcut. However, when I use the same shortcut for solidity code (with .sol extension) I get a notification telling me 'There is no document formatter for solidity files installed'. Does anyone know of an extension that can do the job?

Answer (score 1):

[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) works with solidity files.

There are some issues recently on their GitHub page but I have been using it recently and it does the job.

To use Prettier as a default formatter for solidity files:

- Open any `.sol` file and press `Ctrl + Shift + P`
- Search for `format document with`
- Set the `default formatter` to `Prettier`

Comment: It doesn't support solidity files. please take a look in the linked page you provided.

Comment: Prettier doesn't support solidity. When I tried to format a .sol file, it asked me for solidity formatted and gave the option of the solidity extension by Juan. Then it just works fine.
Try this - `Ctrl + Shift + P` - format document - then it should give you an option to select the solidity extension. 
I have been using it since months now.

Comment: This way, you only get an arbitrary formatting, none of prettier options work, including vertical ruler which is highly needed because of short lines wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with 'Ctrl + S' not working, but then I figured it out.

To format Solidity files within visual studio code we need two extensions:

- [solidity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity)
- [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

To use Prettier as a default formatter for solidity files:

- Open vs code settings (`Ctrl + ,`) and search for *default formatter* and set ***Editor: Default Formatter*** to ***Prettier - Code formatter***
  [Default formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0UcT.png).
- Search for *Format on Save* and enable it.
  [Format on save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucfmi.png)
- Search for *Solidity Formatter* in vs code settings and set the default formatter to ***prettier***.
  [solidity formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad5Fh.png)
- Now you can format your solidity code using `Shift + Alt + F`.

Answer (score -1):

These are the two visual studio integrations listed in the [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/).

- [Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity)
- [Visual Studio Code extension](http://juan.blanco.ws/solidity-contracts-in-visual-studio-code/)

I dont use visual studio so i dont know if its exactly what you are looking for but maybe it helps.

EDIT: I've been using VS and the solidity extension recommended is: [Visual Studio Code extension](http://juan.blanco.ws/solidity-contracts-in-visual-studio-code/)

The extension provides:

- Syntax highlighting
- Snippets
- Compilation of the current contract (Press F1 Solidity : Compile Current Solidity Contract), or F5
- Compilation of all the contracts (Press F1 Solidity : Compile all Solidity Contracts), or Ctrl+F5 / Cmd+F5
- Code completion for all contracts / libraries in the current file and all referenced imports
- Default project structure (solidity files needs to be in the 'src' directory, and libraries in the 'lib' directory). Libraries will follow the same structure.
- Compilation supporting EIP82 (dappfile and dependency packages)
- Support for different solidity versions (Remote and local)
- Code generation using https://github.com/Nethereum/abi-code-gen, it includes currently the default template for Nethereum service, dtos generation. (Open 'contractName.json' after compilation from the bin folder. Press F1 and press - - Solidity: Code generate from compilation output..) Please contribute more templates.
- Linting using Solhint or Solium

Comment: The first one does not work at all. And I had the first one installed. It does syntax higlighting and autocompletion. But still it doesn't do auto formatting when I use ctl+shift+i.